# iterating through Enumeration of hastable keys throws NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, hashtable, enumeration, key

I am trying to iterate through a list of keys from a hash table  using enumeration however I keep getting a NoSuchElementException at the last key in list?

```
Hashtable<String, String> vars = new Hashtable<String, String>();

vars.put("POSTCODE","TU1 3ZU");
vars.put("EMAIL","job.blogs@lumesse.com");
vars.put("DOB","02 Mar 1983");

Enumeration<String> e = vars.keys();

while(e.hasMoreElements()){

System.out.println(e.nextElement());
String param = (String) e.nextElement();
}
```

Console output:

```
EMAIL
POSTCODE
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Hashtable Enumerator
    at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.nextElement(Unknown Source)
    at testscripts.webdrivertest.main(webdrivertest.java:47)
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You call `nextElement()` twice in your loop. This call moves the enumeration pointer forward. 
You should modify your code like the following:

```
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    String param = e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

Answer (score 80):

```
for (String key : Collections.list(e))
    System.out.println(key);
```

Comment: Massively inefficient! `Collections.list` creates a new `ArrayList` and copies each value from the enumeration into the new list before returning the list reference. A very big price to pay for cute syntax.

Comment: @AndyBrown not if your list is small or not very big. And.. cute syntax helps on making the code more clear.

Comment: a shorter variant is Collections.list(e).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: @AndyBrown It's not massively inefficient.  It's O(2n) vs O(n), same order of magnitude.  And for a big enough list, it's possible that with parallel streams and the right hardware, it will be faster to iterate through the list.

Comment: @anataliocs with Collections.list(e) using an ArrayList with initial default size of 10 internally there may me a considerable number of array allocations and copies involved. As ArrayList grows by half it's current size if it's over capacity, an enumeration with 1000 elements would create no less than 13 arrays (sizes 10, 15, 22, 33, 49, 73, 109, 163, 244, 366, 549, 823, 1234) and copy 12 of them

Answer (score 11):

Every time you call `e.nextElement()` you take the next object from the iterator. You have to check `e.hasMoreElement()` between each call.

---

Example:

```
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
    String param = e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the first reply. 
It be the validated answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @PascalGanaye This answer missed the bug the question contained.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling nextElement twice. Refactor like this:

```
while(e.hasMoreElements()){


String param = (String) e.nextElement();
System.out.println(param);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `e.nextElement()` twice inside your loop when you're only guaranteed that you can call it once without an exception. Rewrite the loop like so:

```
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
  String param = e.nextElement();
  System.out.println(param);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling nextElement twice in the loop. You should call it only once, else it moves ahead twice:

```
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
    String s = e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you do `e.nextElement()` you skip one. So you skip two elements in each iteration of your loop.